# Translating Ovid's Fasti 1.149–150

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ovidius

> dic, age, frigoribus quare novus incipit annus,
>     qui melius per ver incipiendus erat?

> Well then, say why the new year begins in the cold, though it should have been begun during the spring.

Is this correct? Why is this *erat* in the imperfect? It is often translated as "spring is much better."

Answer (score 10):

Gildersleeve & Lodge, *Latin grammar*, section 254.2 (in the discussion of the indicative mood) states:

> The Impf. as the Tense of Disappointment is sometimes used in these verbs [= verbs that denote possibility and power, obligation and necessity, *and also other expressions of the same, such as the passive periphrastic*] to denote opposition to a present state of things: **dēbēbam**, *I ought* (but do not); **poterās**, *you could* (but do not). These may be considered as conditionals in disguise.

Therefore, I would translate *qui...incipiendus erat* as something like 'though it would better/more properly deserve to be begun during the spring.'

To me, 'should have been beg[u]n' distorts the point of the Latin text, which is that the year should continue to start in the spring. Also, though I've never encountered all the translations where it's translated as 'spring is much better,' that may work perfectly well in the context of the surrounding translation, however loose it sounds in isolation.